# Is there a way to create argument in python's argparse that returns true in case no values given

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Currently `--resize` flag that I created is boolean, and means that all my objects will be resized:

```
parser.add_argument("--resize", action="store_true", help="Do dictionary resize")

# ...

# if resize flag is true I'm re-sizing all objects
if args.resize:
    for object in my_obects:
        object.do_resize()
```

Is there a way implement argparse argument that if passed as boolean flag (`--resize`) will return true, but if passed with value (`--resize 10`), will contain value.

Example:

1. `python ./my_script.py --resize # Will contain True that means, resize all the objects`
2. `python ./my_script.py --resize <index> # Will contain index, that means resize only specific object`

Comment: I'd recommend picking a value other than `True` to mean resizing all objects. `if args.resize` will trigger on any nonzero integer value of `resize`, and if you try changing that to `if args.resize == True`, it'll still trigger when `args.resize` is `1`, since `True == 1`. The string `'all'` might be a good choice.

Comment: @user2357112 You should *always* check against boolean values using identity. E.g. `if args.resize is True: resizeAll() / elif args.resize: resizeIndex(args.resize)`

Comment: @poke: On the contrary, you should *almost never* check boolean values by identity. Checking booleans using identity is quite strongly counter to the usual practice, and an `is True` check would run a risk of someone removing it without realizing that it's actually necessary in this particular case.

Comment: @user2357112: Generally, what you're saying is perfectly correct. But here we need to distinguish between `True` and various truthy integers, so `if args.resize is True` is appropriate in this circumstance.

Comment: @PM2Ring: `if args.resize is True` is certainly an improvement on the given code, but it's the wrong improvement. Switching `True` for a different value produces code that future maintainers will understand quicker and be much less likely to screw up. Saying that you should *always* check booleans by identity is just plain wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: Fair call. I guess a string like `'all'` is slightly better than using `True`, for the reason you mentioned earlier: it might be "repaired" by a future maintainer. Of course, a brief comment could explain why the explict `is True` test is being used.

Comment: `x is True` is notably different from `x == True`; the latter looks like a mistake, but `is` is done on purpose. Also, PyCharm warns about the latter but not the former.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to optionally accept a value, you need to set [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs) to `'?'`. This will make the argument consume one value if it is specified. If the argument is specified but without value, then the argument will be assigned the argument’s [`const`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) value, so that’s what you need to specify too:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--resize', nargs='?', const=True)
```

There are now three cases for this argument:

1. Not specified: The argument will get its [default value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) (`None` by default):

   ```
   >>> parser.parse_args(''.split())
   Namespace(resize=None)
   ```
2. Specified without a value: The argument will get its const value:

   ```
   >>> parser.parse_args('--resize'.split())
   Namespace(resize=True)
   ```
3. Specified with a value: The argument will get the specified value:

   ```
   >>> parser.parse_args('--resize 123'.split())
   Namespace(resize='123')
   ```

Since you are looking for an index, you can also specify `type=int` so that the argument value will be automatically parsed as an integer. This will not affect the default or const case, so you still get `None` or `True` in those cases:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--resize', nargs='?', type=int, const=True)
>>> parser.parse_args('--resize 123'.split())
Namespace(resize=123)
```

---

Your usage would then look something like this:

```
if args.resize is True:
    for object in my_objects:
        object.do_resize()
elif args.resize:
    my_objects[args.resize].do_resize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `default=False`, `const=True` and `nargs='?'` to the argument definition and remove `action`. This way if you don't pass `--resize` it will store False, if you pass `--resize` with no argument will store `True` and otherwise the passed argument. Still you will have to refactor the code a bit to know if you have index to delete or delete all objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nargs` to accept different number of command-line arguments

Use `default` and `const` to set the default value of resize

see here for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

```
parser.add_argument('-resize', dest='resize', type=int, nargs='?', default=False, const=True)

>>tmp.py -resize 1  
args.resize: 1

>>tmp.py -resize  
args.resize: True

>>tmp.py   
args.resize: False
```